# React - How to know if a component is in a link element synchronously?

Tags: html, reactjs

**Nested links are not allowed in HTML.**

For a component like:

```js
function MyComponent(){
  return (
    <a href='...'>
      {/* ... */}
    <a/>
  );
}
```

How `MyComponent` can get to know synchronously if it has an `<a>` element ancestor ?
So it could adapt on its 1st render ?

Answer (score 1):

*This answers the original version of the question, which has since been edited*

---

You can use `closest` with a React `ref` for this:

```
const SmartLink = ({ href, children }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current?.parentElement.closest("a")) {
      throw new Error("<a /> elements can't be nested");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <a ref={ref} href={href}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-monad-smoyx?file=/src/App.js:354-397)

Comment: Nice. But to make this check, one has to render the element in the DOM (making willingly the html error). And he will be able to correct the component only on the 2nd render. Isn't  there a way to know on the first render synchronously  (like a context) ?

Comment: Not trivially. Maybe if you want to try messing around with `React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` or something (yes, that's a real property name of the React object). May I ask _why_ you want to do this? Seems like something that might be handy during development/debugging, but not something you'd want to rely on in production, so why is "on the first render synchronously" important?